# Creating Http request or proxy authentication to access a site using a token

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, http-headers

```
public void Setup()
{
    _driver = Driver.GenerateWebDriver(browser, "local");
    var network = _driver.Manage().Network;
    network.AddRequestHandler(new NetworkRequestHandler
    {
        RequestMatcher = data => data.Url.Contains("www-stage.ibselectronics.com"),
            RequestTransformer = data =>
            {
                if (data.Method == "POST")
                {
                    var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.PostData);
                    var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
                    data.PostData = base64String;
                }
                data.Headers["CF-Access-Client-Id"] = "token here.access";
                data.Headers["CF-Access-Client-Secret"] = "token here";
                return data;
            },
    });
    Task task = network.StartMonitoring();
    _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(baseUrl);
    task.Wait();
}
```

> this is my code I put it on setup so that before the browser will open
> this code will be execute but I encounter this error "One or more
> errors occurred. (Unexpected error creating WebSocket DevTools
> session.)" hope someone there will help any advice on how this will be
> execute or there is another way to post access a site using http
> header request ?

- 

Comment: how to configure a custom network request handler that adds those two HTTP headers This is my follow up Question